# Using which one of this is efficient 'WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 'or 'ELSE'?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

In the below two block of codes im using  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
and else which one will be efficient to use.

```
if outrowcount = 1 then     
  update Extable set CLIENT_COUNT = outCliCount where cname='xxx';  
  outretvalue := 0;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     outretvalue := -1;
```

or

```
if outrowcount = 1 then     
   update Extable set CLIENT_COUNT = outCliCount where cname='xxx';  
   outretvalue := 0;  
 else
   outretvalue := -1;
```

Comment: If you would like to a return value if outrowcount = 1 and update record, then if else method will be better rather than EXCEPTION approach IMHO.

Comment: @polppan ok fine, then when to use WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND?

Comment: `No_DATA_FOUND` exception is used when you would want to catch an exception if your select query fails to fetch records. A good example of this can be found [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01403)

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE statement never throws NO_DATA_FOUND exception. It only sets implicit SQL cursor state, which you can check using SQL%ROWCOUNT for example. So you sample would be

```
update Extable set CLIENT_COUNT = outCliCount where cname='xxx'; 
if SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 then
  outretvalue := -1;
else
  outretvalue := 0;
end if;
```

Comment: It was helpful, then in which case  NO_DATA_FOUND  should be used?

Comment: NO_DATA_FOUND should be used when you are performing a Select query. That is because, the select statement does not populate SQL%ROWCOUNT. So, in general, for DML's there is no need to handle exceptions (because you will never get NO_DATA_FOUND) but for Selects you should.

Comment: @ Vaibhav  i have a doubt If i use SELECT like this>>>"select CLIENT_COUNT from Extable where cname='xxx'"  instead of UPDATE in the example Petr posted will sql%ROWCOUNT returns the no of rows fetched or not??

Comment: In PLSQL you have to use SELECT ... INTO ... clause, which has to return exactly one row. If it selects more rows, it throws TOO_MANY_ROWS exception, if none, it throws NO_DATA_FOUND. So if you need to get count of selected rows, use SELECT count(*)  INTO your_variable from Extable where cname = 'xxx'

Comment: u mean i cant use sql%rowcount for SELECT, and i have to use count(*) to fetch rows affected?

Comment: You can, but it will always return either 1 or an exception. In PLSQL you can select data by usign cursor or select exactly one single row using SELECT INTO